# wp_get_theme() works fine, but wp_get_themes() returns empty array

Tags: themes

I am writing a code snippet for use in ManageWP, to extract some of the more basic audit info.

In the snippet, `wp_get_theme()` works fine, and returns correct info about the theme, and can be used to get parent theme info too.

BUT

I try to use `wp_get_themes()`, with no args, and it only returns an empty array.

Example code:

```
$theme_name = wp_get_theme()->get( 'Name' );
$theme_dir = get_stylesheet();
$parent_theme = $parent_dir = '';
if ( is_object( wp_get_theme()->parent() ) ) {
    $parent_theme = wp_get_theme()->parent()->name;
    $parent_dir = get_template();
}
$all_themes = wp_get_themes();
print_r( $all_themes );

Array
(
)
```

Recommendations?

Comment: Is this in Multisite, or in a single-site installation?

Comment: It's a single site.  Tested on multiple sites

Comment: I just dumped your code into my test plugin and in a shortcode it works fine, dumps all the themes.  Where/when are you calling the code?

Comment: Anything unusual about your theme directories?  Any plugins that might be messing with the arguments ? or directory structure?

Comment: I should have added, that I'm able to run the snippet on multiple sites, all different servers, themes, setups, etc.  Same results.  I'm wondering if the "code snippet" is running too early in the load process.

Comment: I found that if I run the same basic code as a shortcode, the function works fine, so I believe the ManageWP 'Code Snippets' are running before the system is fully initialized.

Comment: The code given just works fine with a test env where wordpress 5.1.1 is installed with a half a dozen themes .